# reversing a single character in Java

Tags: java

Is there any way to reverse a character in Java, i.e reversing "(" into ")". I tried String buffer, of course it did not work because it does not reverse a character but a string of more than one character. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You would have to create a mapping of "reverse" characters yourself and apply it. Standard library doesn't provide that.

Comment: Please consider terminology: you cannot reverse a single character in the meaning that "reverse" has in a string programming context. What you are asking is how to mirror, or perhaps flip, a character, so to clarify that situation: `(` and `)` are not each other's mirror image at all, depending on the font used, so it depends _entirely_ on the font, and then for that particular font, you'll need to create a lookup that specifies pairs of "looks like they're mirrored" characters.

Comment: This sounds more like you want to find a *closing* brace to an opening brace. In ASCII there are only three I guess: brackets: [], (curly) braces {} and parentheses: (). For them you can make a map. If you go into Unicode jungle, well, you may need to bring an elephant gun.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

You cannot do that unless you provide a map of the characters you want to replace and with what you want to replace them.

Then you iterate the string, find if the char has a "reverse" char in your map, and if so, replace it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to reverse a character in Java

The simple answer is No.  Not in any of the standard APIs.  (And AFAIK not in any of the commonly used 3rd-party libraries; Apache Commons, Guava, etcetera.)

Why?

- Because this kind of thing is rarely called for.  (I don't recall ever seeing a request like this before on StackOverflow.)  The Java designers wisely do not front-load the standard APIs with obscure methods that are rarely if ever going to be used.
- Because the notion of "reverse" is not well defined:

  - If you want a character whose glyph is the mirror image of some other character, that is not a tractable problem.  The glyphs depend on the `Font` used.  For example a *`(`* and *`)`* are not mirror images.  (At least on my screen they aren't!)
  - If you want something where one code point inherently<sup>1</sup> *means* the opposite or reverse of another, that is intractable because code points don't have any *inherent* meaning<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1 - What is the opposite of "N"?  Is it "Y"?  Would someone in France agree?  What about "A"?  A geneticist would give you a different answer to a numerologist.  My point: there are *many ways* to ascribe meaning to code points.</sup>

<sup>2 -  Apart from corresponding to an abstraction (a letter, a number, a symbol, etcetera) which typically *also* doesn't have a single inherent meaning.</sup>

---

So what is the solution?

Implement your own notion of "reverse" for yourself using a simple lookup table.